# Conditional Excel Lookup

Tags: conditional-statements, vlookup

I have week days in Column A and values in Column B
I want to look up the column B values that correspond to all the "Thursdays" in Column A and return the lowest of those values.
My apologies if this is a daft question. It's literally been years since I've worked with Excel formulas and I'm rusty.
Many thanks.

Comment: use Pivot Tables, not Vlookup: http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/datamanagementinexcel/ss/8912pivot_table.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could use MIN formula like

```
=MIN(IF(A:A="Thursday",B:B))
```

please note that this is an array formula and you will have to declare it by

Ctrl+Shift+Enter

So once you typed the formula do Ctrl+Shift+Enter